# Django virtualenvwrapper environment variables in production

Tags: django, gunicorn, virtualenvwrapper

I'm setting up a Django project on a server, following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn) guide on DigitalOcean. However, I'm very unfamiliar with Gunicorn and nginx, so I'm running into issues.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.7, Django 2.1.3, virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4, gunicorn 19.9.0.

When running `curl --unix-socket /run/gunicorn.sock localhost` returns `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

I'm suspecting it is the way I handle the `SECRET_KEY` of Django.

I'm using virtualenvwrapper to handle my virtual environments and set environment variables in the `postactivate` and unset them in `predeactivate` in the following manner:

`postactivate`:

```
if [[ -n $SECRET_KEY ]]
then
    export SECRET_KEY_BACKUP=$SECRET_KEY
fi
export SECRET_KEY='my-secret-key'
```

`predeactivate`:

```
if [[ -n $SECRET_KEY_BACKUP ]]
then
    export SECRET_KEY=$SECRET_KEY_BACKUP
    unset SECRET_KEY_BACKUP
else
    unset SECRET_KEY
```

It's clear that the variables are not available unless the virtual env is activated. I retrieve the variables in `settings.py` with `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`.

How do gunicorn work with virtual environments? Is there a way to have gunicorn activate the environment?
Otherwise, what is best practice when it comes to the SECRET_KEY?

Thank you very much!

Edit: Added variable retrieval method.

Edit2: systemd service-file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<name>
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/<name>/projects/<projectname>/<appname>
ExecStart=/home/<name>/.virtualenvs/<appname>/bin/gunicorn \
    --access-logfile - \
    --workers 3 \
    --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
    <appname>.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What makes you think it has anything to do with the secret key? But gunicorn doesn't know or care about your virtualenv, you would need to activate it in whatever job is starting gunicorn.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I thought it was the secret_key, because I wondered 'How will it know'. But I guess you're right. It's not only the secret_key, it's the environment... I'm using `systemd` to start gunicorn, as per the guide, but I know very little about that. But I guess that might the real issue, activating the env along with gunicorn?

Comment: You should show your service file.

Comment: I've added it in an edit.

Comment: Would it make sense to add something like `ExecStart=source /home/<name>/.virtualenvs/<projectname>/bin/activate` to `[Service]` in the systemd service file?